# Runtime populated enum-like class

Tags: java

I have many objects using few classes (means elements visual categorization like in html+css). Classes are not known at compile-time and they are used in conditions many times.

To improve performance I've got one solution:

```
public class ElementClass {

    private static final Map<String, ElementClass> classes = new HashMap<>();

    public final String name;
    public final String lowerName;

    public ElementClass(String name, String lowerName) {
        this.name = name;
        this.lowerName = lowerName;
    }

    public static ElementClass get(String name) {
        String lower = name.toLowerCase();
        ElementClass c = classes.get(lower);
        if (c == null) {
            c = new ElementClass(name, lower);
            classes.put(lower, c);
        }
        return c;
    }
}
```

The method `get` is used very less than comparison of `ElementClass` variables. It is in parsing configurations and for some `static` variables. I'm not sure if this is the best way to go, because I'm Java beginner.

The examples usage of `ElementClass`:

```
// contains element styles based on it's class
Map<ElementClass,ElementStyle> styles;

void exampleFunction() {
    ElementClass c = ElementClass.get("special");
    for( Element e : elements ) {
        if( e.cls == c ) doSomethingSpecial();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an usage example of this thing, i.e. some client?

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean with classes? I get confused. ElementClass is something from your application data model, not related to Java Classes, right?

Comment: @TobiasN.Sasse Yes, it's not related to Java Classes. It means mostly visual style categorization of elements. I've put it into question.

Comment: If all you do is compare by identify, you might as well use instances of String to represent your categories. Is your question really that easy to answer or did you forget a requirement ...?

Comment: @meriton I'm c++ programmer and in c++ it would be big performance improvement. I've just moved to Java and don't know if I'm doing it right.

Comment: I don't see any mayor flaw to your implementation yet. It might be a bit over the top to create a class for just two Strings, but I am sure there is more going on in your application ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a textbook implementation of a cache. If there aren't many ElementClasses and if your program is single-threaded, this will be enough.

I don't see the need to keep the lowercase name inside the `ElementClass`. It is enough to use it as the map key. I also assume there's more to the `ElementClass` in your project since now it just contains a name.

## Update

After clarification it became obvious that you do indeed only intend to use the `String name`. In such a case it would be much better to make each `Element` just contain its lowercase name, but *interned*:

```
public Element(String name) {
  this.name = name.toLowerCase().intern();
}
```

Then you can compare `element.name == "special"` and be guaranteed to match any names that are equal to "special".

Comment: Downvoter, if you have an issue with my response, please leave a comment! This is a very thorough and thought-through answer!

Comment: I didn't downvote. I've fixed method to be static. It was written minute before question and I haven't tested it yet.

Comment: Do you plan to have any code inside the `ElementClass`, or is it just for comparison? I suggest you to put the code like `someSpecialCode` inside the class so you don't need the `if`s. You could just execute `someSpecialCode` for each item, but the implementation will vary accordingly.

Comment: If using only for comparison, then why not just a plain String?

Comment: It's much more easier to compare pointers than strings and they are compared many times.

Comment: Why not simply use `==` to compare `Strings`, then, instead of `.equals()`?  That will do identity comparison.

Comment: But this still doesn't motivate a whole class. You can just `intern` all the Strings and use == on them.

Comment: When it's parsed from file I think that two strings containing same characters don't have to be same instances of String.

Comment: I suggest you google that one. It's widely available. Basically, it's a system-wide internal string cache that holds all compile-time string constants plus all other strings explicitily `intern`ed.